# How to embed WAR structure into desktop application?

Tags: java, user-interface, war, vaadin

We have an application written in Java in which the UI will be a relatively small part. We want to create a modern, consumer orientated UI and came to the conclusion that Swing would not be able to offer what we were after. After much deliberation, we decided to try build the UI using Vaadin, as although our application can not run on the web (it is p2p), Vaadin offered a fluid and good looking experience out of the box. Because of of this our application does not have a WAR structure which is required for Vaadin.

The idea is that we'll create a small embeded web server that will serve up a Vaadin UI to the user's local web browser (which we'll launch using java.awt.Desktop.browse()). We still have the problem though of how to go about embedding a WAR structure into an existing project. Our build tool is Maven and you can view the project source code: https://github.com/sanity/tahrir

Comment: If you like HTML based interfaces... why not go for something like [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html)?

Comment: Or perhaps the [Appcelerator's Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Comment: Linux support is a must for us and I don't believe either offer such. A disadvantage of both is also that they are proprietary.

Comment: Titanium, is opensource: https://github.com/appcelerator/

Comment: Sadly, Air no longer supports linux http://www.adobe.com/es/products/air/faq.html#linux

Answer (score 1):

You can embed Jetty: Here is [how](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty).

Example:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
Context root = new Context(server,"/",Context.SESSIONS);
root.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet("Ciao")), "/*");
server.start();
```

If you want to run a **WAR**, [here](http://bachman.pl/devel/running-your-webapp-inside-embedded-jetty/) is an example on how to do that

Here is the relevant code:

```
server = new Server();
Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(PORT);
connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
server.addConnector(connector);

WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext();
wac.setContextPath("/");
wac.setWar("./web");    // this is path to the .WAR 
server.setHandler(wac);
server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
server.start();
```

Comment: Our application is not a RIA and thus does not have a WAR structure. We don't want to change the structure of our application as the UI is a relatively small part. The main problem is not running the server locally but allowing us to use Vaadin without a WAR structure for the entire project but instead perhaps embed it into it.

Comment: You do not need a WAR structure. You just need the .jar of your app, and a .war right next to it (or embedded inside the .jar)

Comment: In your question you ask "We still have the problem though of _how to go about **embedding a WAR structure** into an existing project_. " Well, assuming your app is in a .jar, you just copy the .war in the same folder as the .jar and use a relative path to find it from your .jar app

Comment: Luxspes is correct. We ship a Java app with an embedded Jetty and this works fine. May I also add that Maven philosophy is to separate concerns. You should have a small separate Maven project that contains your web components and required librairies and builds a war. Then you assemble everything (Jetty+War+Other Jars) using the Maven assembly-plugin or otherwise into an app.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin *is* a web application framework - and web applications will expect to have a WAR structure.

Now, if you're trying to avoid having stick all your classes in WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes - that's fine. By embedding Jetty, you can use all the classes on the classpath without having to stick them in a certain place.

However, you'll have to do a fair bit of work constructing and configuring the web application within Jetty. I imagine the easiest approach to create a WAR structure within your JAR on the class path (or to create a sibling WAR) with all of the other webresources such as WEB-INF/web.xml, VAADIN/themes etc. - but without the WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes - which is what I *think* you are trying to avoid.

Note, I have not done this myself, but I believe that's both possible and the path of least resistance.